# How to collect performance metrics from running google cloud ml training instances?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I'm running a model on google cloud ml training, and it's taking about 10 hours with some naive guesses at the shapes of the machine. I'd like to optimize it a bit to cut down on running time and overall cost.

What's the best way to determine if I'm using the resources effectively? I'd like cpu measurements, memory pressure, and GPU usage (whenever they are available). I suspect I'd need to either 1) log these or 2) install a monitoring agent like stack driver, and assume things like nvidia-smi are locatable, but I'm curious if any one has tried.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now built-in into the product -- the CPU and RAM usage metrics (for now) are published as a Stackdriver metrics.

A view of the metrics is also displayed in the console on the job detail page.

Hope that helps.